# Javascript promise returns unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

Hi am trying to use request module with promise in nodeJS.

Here is my Script

```
require('promise');
var request = require('request');           
const requestget = function (url) {
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            resolve(body);

         } else {
            reject(error);
         }
       });
  });
}
requestget('http://www.modulus.io').then(console.log);
```

but am getting the following error.

```
/home/xyz/reques.js:14
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) {
                                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

I really don't know what's wrong in this script any one can help me out.

Comment: choose between `function (resolve, reject) {` or `(resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I was using a very early version of Node. Arrow functions landed in version ~8.

Answer (score 5):

On this line, you need to make sure you are defining a function. You can do this using arrow functions like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

Arrow functions have the syntax `(param1, param2) => {function body}`, which is the same thing as saying `function(param1, param2) {function body}`. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Hi tried the same but am getting error like this.

'. /home/xyz/reques.js:5
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >'

Comment: try using `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {` instead then. you could also run node with `node --harmony` if you want the latest features like arrow functions as they are now the recommended way of doing this (to preserve scope)

Comment: thanks it works like charm `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)` still I don't know why `=>` function not working

Comment: you're using an older version of node. You can make it work if you run it with `node --harmony`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use arrow functions without arrows.

```
require('promise');
var request = require('request');           
const requestget = function (url) {
  //Add the arrow on the below line
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            resolve(body);

         } else {
            reject(error);
         }
       });
  });
}
requestget('http://www.modulus.io').then(console.log);
```

Comment: still am getting the following error:

`/home/xyz/reques.js:5
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3`

Comment: You may have an older version of node, upgrade to anything past node v6 and you will have full support.

If that's not an option just use new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    //Code here
});